# Toggle UITextView scrollEnabled

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview

I initialized UITextView with `scrollEnabled = true`. 
But once I set `scrollEnabled = false`, the text view does not scroll even after I've set `scrollEnabled = true`

Is there another way I could toggle the textView's scrolling? 
I have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `true`.

In

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.addSubview(textView)
}
```

In

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 180 {
        textView.scrollEnabled  = true // This does not work!
    } else {
        textView.scrollEnabled  = false // This works!
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you create/enable/disable to scrolling and text view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get you,what you are trying. It's working for me.Just try like this below this code.

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = sender;
    switch (btn.tag) {
        case 0://enabled
            [customTextView setScrollEnabled:YES];
            break;
        case 1://disable
            [customTextView setScrollEnabled:NO];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    } }
```